# Как посчитать выручку от кредита/долга?

Tags: mysql, алгоритм, математика

Возможности проконсультироваться с бухгалтером у меня нет, поэтому надеюсь на то, что здесь есть люди, которые смогут мне помочь.

У меня есть 3 таблицы

```
-товар
-клиенты
-продажи
-задолженности
```

Таблица товаров имеет такие столбцы:

```
-сер.номер
-имя
-себестоимость
-количество
и другие..
```

Таблица продажи показывает выручку от продажи товара и имеет такие столбцы:

```
-сер.номер
-сер.номер товара
-цена продажи
-количество
- выручка ( цена продажи * количество) - (себестоимость * количество) = сумма
и другие..
```

Далее кредит, и с этим у меня возникли проблемы; я просто не знаю как посчитать выручку в таком случае
Например, себестоимость товара 300$; его продали Ивану за 600$

Иван заплатил:

```
15.08.2020 - 100$ - теперь его долг: 500$
21.08.2020 - 300$ - теперь его долг:200$
28.08.2020 - 100$ - теперь его долг:100$
19.09.2020 - 100$ - теперь его долг:0$
```

Как в таком случае посчитать выручку товара и занести в таблицу продажи?
Возможно, мой подход изначально не правильный и есть другой алгоритм; буду рад, если вы поможете мне.
Надеюсь, понятно сформулировал вопрос, иначе пишите в комментариях - дополню вопрос.